# How to add Amchart charts in Extjs 4 Panel?

Tags: extjs4, amcharts

I want to add Amchart charts in ExtJS Panel How can I do this?

see below Amchart code

How to add this designed chart on ExtJS Panel

```
var columnChartData = [
            {
                "name": "John",
                "points": 35654,
                "color": "#7F8DA9",
                "bullet": "images/0.gif"
            }
        ];

     var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = columnChartData;
            chart.categoryField = "name";
            chart.startDuration = 1;
           // WRITE
            chart.write("example-grid");
```

//Write this chart on Extjs Panel

Answer (score 0):

add( component ) :

Adds Component(s) to this Container.

Description:
•Fires the beforeadd event before adding.
•The Container's default config values will be applied accordingly (see defaults for details).
•Fires the add event after the component has been added.

Notes:

If the Container is already rendered when add is called, it will render the newly added Component into its content area.

If the Container was configured with a size-managing layout manager, the Container will recalculate its internal layout at this time too.

Note that the default layout manager simply renders child Components sequentially into the content area and thereafter performs no sizing.

If adding multiple new child Components, pass them as an array to the add method, so that only one layout recalculation is performed.

```
tb = new Ext.toolbar.Toolbar({
    renderTo: document.body
});  // toolbar is rendered
// add multiple items.
// (defaultType for Toolbar is 'button')
tb.add([{text:'Button 1'}, {text:'Button 2'}]);
```

To inject components between existing ones, use the insert method.

to do a dinamic load of new views use .add(component) on your panel.
maybe you should do a panel.refresh() if the new component is added but not shown

Comment: You mean I need to add my chart object to Extjs.panel items -It is not working as I already tried this